# how to set custom drawable background on android?

Tags: android, layout, nine-patch

i have this resource
[image]

i use this 9 patched image as my list item background. but something went wrong when on my layout xml it shown like this:

[image]

as you can see, the contents are not properly placed inside the box.
this is how i define my list item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_image"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_left" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/item_text_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#8cc751"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Name"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/item_text_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#909090"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Message"
        />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

i have no idea why this is happening. any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: It usually happens with 9patch images. Delete this files from Drawables and copy it again from wherever you have copied earlier to the Drawable folder

Comment: You have manually given layout_width and layout_height to imageview.........try changing these two parameters to adjust your text inside the image

Answer (score 0):

9 patch image is just background. You have to adjust your views. See.. From your image `M` is straight below to the `N`. So you can move your second `textview` or both to some pixels right, For example you can add `marginLeft`.

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/item_text_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#909090"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Message"
        />
```

I hope this suggestion will help you.